# unobtrusive-ajax not working when using new version of Jquery in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, ajax.beginform

I have try to send a Ajax Post web request. When clicking the submit button it's redirect to the Ajax url.When i change my jquery current version to jquery-1.7.1 it will work fine. how can i get the correct version of unobtrusive-ajax script correspond to 2.1.1
Below are my complete code.

**View Code**

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function getNextMessage() {
            $.post("@Url.Action("GetNextMessage")", function (message) {
                $("<li>").text(message).appendTo("#messages");
                getNextMessage();
            });
        }

        getNextMessage();
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <h2>
            Chat
        </h2>
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostMessage", new AjaxOptions()))
        {
            <p>
                Say : @Html.TextBox("message")
                <input type="submit"/>
            </p>
        }
    </body>


</html>
```

**Controller Code**

```
 public class ChatController : Controller
    {
        static  TaskCompletionSource<string > _nextMessage=new TaskCompletionSource<string>(); 

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public async  Task<string>  GetNextMessage()
        {
            //await Task.Delay(2000);
            //return "Hello at : " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            return await _nextMessage.Task;
        }

        public void PostMessage(string message )
        {
           _nextMessage.SetResult(message);
            _nextMessage = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your `JsonResult`? Why is `getNextMessage()` infinitely looping?

Comment: it is long polling. my question is about regarding the version problem